# jQuery; How can I return ajax returned data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function, return

I'm trying to return AJAX response data like below..

```
        function reqNodelistByField( i ) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: './req.nodelist.by.field.php',
                dataType: 'text',
                data: { field_id:i },
                success: function(data) {
                    r = $.parseJSON(data);

                    if(r.valid === false) r = false;
                }
            });
            alert(r);

            return r;
        };
```

Response `data` is perfect. However I don't know how to return this `data` outside the function.

Only I can see from `alert(r)` is `undefined`.

How can I return `data`?

Comment: The first *A* of AJAX means *asynchronous*. Your AJAX call happens outside the flow of your function.

Comment: How do you want to use the data? Show it in some element? Or use the data to do something else?

Comment: Thanks Matt. I just add `async: false` in my code and now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alert(r) is undefined because you are perfoming an asynchronous call, in other words, your script makes the call and continue executing the code without wait for call's response. For that, you need return the `r` in the ajax success function.

```
 function reqNodelistByField( i ) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: './req.nodelist.by.field.php',
                dataType: 'text',
                data: { field_id:i },
                success: function(data) {
                    r = $.parseJSON(data);

                    if(r.valid == false) {
                         return false
                    }
                    else{
                         return true
                     }
                }
            });
        };
```

Comment: I forgot "asynchronous".. so I just add `async: false` in my code and work perfectly as I expected. Thank you!!

Comment: my advice, dont use `async: false` because if your ajax call takes a lot time, your page will not render properly. Find a best way to execute your code inside the success function.

Answer (score 0):

try this :-

```
function reqNodelistByField( i,callback) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: './req.nodelist.by.field.php',
            dataType: 'text',
            data: { field_id:i },
            success: function(data) {
                r = $.parseJSON(data);
                callback(r);
                //if(r.valid === false) r = false;
            }
        });

    };
```

use it like :-

```
reqNodelistByField("value of i",function(r){
// here you use the r i.e data from ajax request
// check  here 
  if(r.valid === false){
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Done [Docs here](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/).

```
function reqNodelistByField( i ) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: './req.nodelist.by.field.php',
                dataType: 'text',
                data: { field_id:i },
            }).done(function(r){
                alert (r)
                console.log(r)
                });
        };
```