# How can I re-program this jQuery function to be vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery function that I would like to change to plain JavaScript.

```
function readZipCodes() {
     var zipCodes = [];
      $.ajax({
           url: 'data/ZipCodeDatabase.csv',
           contentType: "text/csv",
           async: false,
           success: function(text) {
                zipCodes = text.split("\n");
           }
      });
      return zipCodes;
 }
```

Can you please show me how to rewrite it?

Comment: While you are at it, I would recommend rewriting it to be asynchronous. Synchronous AJAX is deprecated outside of workers, and can lock up the browser, and it's just plain lazy.

Comment: See [jQuery; How can I return ajax returned data? \[duplicate\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25176690/jquery-how-can-i-return-ajax-returned-data) and [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) for more info.